# Magento 1.9.1.0 installation issue on Ubuntu

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I downloaded Magento 1.9.1.0 from magento.com website. When I try to install after unzip the down loader it gives me following error:

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

[image]

Comment: please check log at this file `var/log/apache/error_log` in this file write what is the issue behind **HTTP ERROR 500**

Answer (score 1):

I too got similar kind of error it was my apache config file that was messed, I recommend you to follow this tutorial it will definitely help you in smooth installation.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Please enable errors from index.php file from the root of magento installation .
To enable the errors replace the code below:-

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

umask(0);
```

with:-

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
```

Now it will display you the actual cause of error which can be further handled